# How can I get all checkbox values via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've following checkboxes:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-0" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z1x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-1" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z2x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-2" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z3x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-3" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z4x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-4" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z5x">
```

I'm looking now for a way to receive all checked checkboxes in a string array or object with jQuery. It needs to look like this if I'm checking the corresponding boxes:

```
var arr =["z1x", "z5x"];
```

Any idea how to make this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter by input with name 'trial': `'input[name:trial]'`
2. Filter by whether the input is checked: `':checked'`
3. Use JQuery's map function to iterate over all returned elements: `$.map( array, func )`
4. Replace each element in the array with the `id` data from each element: `(elem) => elem.dataset.id`
5. Return the array

```js
function getChecked() {
    return $.map($('input[name=trial]:checked'), (elem) => elem.dataset.id )
}    

$( function() {
   $('#button').click(() => console.log(getChecked()))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-0" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z1x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-1" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z2x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-2" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z3x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-3" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z4x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-4" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z5x">
<input type="button" id="button">test</input>
```

Comment: I recommend this :) Thanks for your help mate! By the way I think we can remove the () around elem because we only have one parameter.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Yup, but it's a stylistic preference.

Comment: @Mr.Jo somewhat tangentially :)  `({dataset}) => dataset.id` would work instead of `elem => elem.dataset.id` but `{dataset} => dataset.id` gives malformed parameter list, so it's not 100% just stylistic

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the checked checkboxes with jQuery using a CSS selector and then use [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to keep the value each has for its `data-id` attribute:

```js
var checked = [].map.call($("[id |= 'mc']:checked"), element => element.dataset.id);

console.log(checked);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-0" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z1x" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-1" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z2x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-2" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z3x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-3" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z4x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-4" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z5x" checked>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:checked` in a selector string to select the checked checkboxes, and map them to their `data-id` value with `Array.from`'s mapper function:

```js
document.onclick = () => {
  const arr = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('[name=trial]:checked'),
    checkbox => checkbox.dataset.id
  );
  console.log(arr);
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-0" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z1x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-1" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z2x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-2" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z3x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-3" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z4x">
<input type="checkbox" id="mc-4" name="trial" value="abc" data-id="z5x">
```